# Angular UI-Grid: Grouping rows that have the same value in another row

Tags: angular, grouping, angular-ui-grid

I want to customize my Angular ui-grid to look like the one below. 
[image: Example of Table I need to make]
The data is structured as so...

```
{
  name: "Kevin Johar",
  team: "Red",
  id: "2137",
  company: "BlueHerring",
  active: "true",
  date: "05-13-2018",
  team Lead: "John Deer",
  comments: ""
}
```

I want the data to be displayed so that all the different id's assigned to Kevin are organized similar to the grid above. 
So if Kevin had 5 id's assigned to him, the column with his name would be one big block and the rest of the data about each id would follow as normal but staying in the confines of the name column block labeled Kevin.

**Grid Options**

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  flatEntityAccess: true,
  enableGridMenu: true,
  enableFiltering: true,
  exporterMenuCsv: false,
  exporterMenuPdf: false,
  paginationPageSizes: [50, 100, 200],
  paginationPageSize: 100,
  // treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible: false,
  // enableHorizontalScrollbar: 2,
  enableSorting: true
};
```

**Column Defs**

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
  {
    name: 'Name',
    field: 'Name',
    width: 140,
    //Allows user input in these columns
    enableCellEdit: false,
    enableGrouping: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Team',
    field: 'teamName',
    width: 140,
    enableCellEdit: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Id',
    field: 'id',
    width: 100,
    enableCellEdit: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Company',
    field: 'companyName',
    width: 130,
    enableCellEdit: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Active',
    field: 'activePassive',
    width: 140,
    enableCellEdit: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Date',
    field: 'date',
    width: 120,
    enableCellEdit: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Team Lead',
    field: 'teamLead',
    width: 150,
    enableCellEdit: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Comments',
    field: 'comments',
    width: 200,
    enableCellEdit: true
  },
```

];